# Get non-contiguous columns from a list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there any way to get non-contiguous columns from a list of lists in python using comprehension? I mean, if we have a list:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

and i want the first and third column, i.e.:

```
[[1,3],[4,6]]
```

can i get that list with a sentence similar to:

```
[row[1,3] for row in a]
```

??

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(0,2), a)
[(1, 3), (4, 6)]
>>>
```

or as a list comprehension

```
>>> [itemgetter(0,2)(i) for i in a]
[(1, 3), (4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This'll work:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> [(x[0], x[2]) for x in a]
[(1, 3), (4, 6)]
```